# how to get data to textbox from the database 

Tags: sql, vb.net, sqldatareader

I have a form with one combo box and text box, and an SQL database
 named `balance` with two columns; one as `customername` and the other as `obbalance`. 
I had bound all of the customer name to the combo box, now what I  have to do is, 
 when a user selects a customer name from the combo box, the text box should show the obbalance of the selected `customername`; here, the customer name will not be repeated - only one name per customer.
What can I do? Please help me.

```
Dim conectionstring As String
    conectionstring = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\SHOPPROJECT\SHOPPROJECT\shop.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"


    Dim ST As String = ComboBox1.SelectedText

    Dim sqlcon As New SqlConnection(conectionstring)

    Dim sqlcmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT OBBALANCE FROM BALANCE WHERE CUSTOMERNAME =  " & " '" & ST & "'" & "", sqlcon)
    MessageBox.Show(TextBox1.Text)


    Dim result As Object

    Try
        sqlcon.Open()
        ' Dim sdr As SqlDataReader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader()
        result = sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar()

        If result IsNot Nothing Then
            TextBox1.Text = result.ToString()
            MessageBox.Show(TextBox1.Text)

        End If

    Catch ex As SqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

    End Try
End Sub
```

I've tried this, but I can't see the value in the text box, and obbalance is a floating-point value from the SQL database.

Comment: i wanna make them to see wat can i do sir

Answer (score 1):

Set a breakpoint and ensure you are getting the value for OBBALANCE (see if you are getting any rows period might be good). Also, make sure you can only get one row, as you are iterating forward, even when you only need one value.

Better yet, consider ExecuteScalar, which only returns a single value. While you are at it, parameterize the SQL query so you don't get SQL injected.

UPDATE: Just change it here:

sdr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader()

to something like

Dim s as String = sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar()

Then use s as your textbox value. You may have to ToString() the value or otherwise cast as string, as I believe the ExecuteScalar() returns an object.

Comment: can u write code for it execute scalar for this plz and i had set break point for tat obbalance its nullthere so only can u plz help i have to read only one data only wich matches tat selected customer plz can u chage the above code as u knw plz ......

Answer (score 1):

Make the follwing changes:

```
Dim sqlcmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT OBBALANCE FROM BALANCE WHERE CUSTOMERNAME = '" & ST & "'", sqlcon)


TextBox1.Text = sdr.GetString(yourColumnIndex)
```

`ComboBox1.SelectedText` returns the highlighted (selected) text on the `ComboBoxControl`. That will be empty if you haven't use your mouse to select a portion of its text or hold the shift while you are pressing the direction keys on your keyboard. And that's probably why your query returns **ZERO RECORDS**.

Use the following instead:

```
Dim ST As String = ComboBox1.SelectedItem.Text
```

Comment: i used combobox.selecteditem.text but it shows a error tat we cant change a data.row value to string

Comment: i applied can u do one favour can u try in u r home now and plz see

Comment: no sir still i cant find any solution can u plz help me ........i need to finish my project i tried searching net i cant understand plz help me

Comment: no error its not showing any value in tat vb.net from textbox

Comment: Sir y cant u try it there now and see plz ......... as friend do this one favour for me plz sir

Comment: I cant because I dont have the same environment as you do... Try to place some break points ..

Comment: i kept sir but its not showing were it happen is try something my problem is still the textbox is blank nothing is happening in tat textbox sir

Comment: Edit your question and replace the old code with the new code you are using now and we'll see..

Answer (score 1):

If you're updating a text box, is this a single result (scalar value)?  If so, the first thing I'd do is use ExecuteScalar not ExecuteReader.  Then, use debug mode with breakpoints to get a better idea of what is actually happening.  It may simply be that you're not getting any results.

Note: I'm assuming the bad coding practice (in-line sql statement, hard-coded connection string, etc.) are for clarity.  If they're not, fix them.

Comment: can u write code for it execute scalar for this plz and i had set break point for tat obbalance its nullthere so only can u plz help i have to read only one data only wich matches tat selected customer plz can u chage the above code as u knw plz ..

Comment: I don't write VB, maybe one of the other big-brains here can help with the actual code.  You could also look at the msdn website for 'SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar'  That would probably point you in the right direction.