# Get data from SQL Server database into label

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, label

In my ASP.Net webpage, I have a label and need the label's text to be retrieved from my database.

I have no problem writing to my database, but it seems trying to retieve the data again is a mission...

What I need is to get the data from the `Price` column in my database, from the table `Tickets`, from the record where the `ConcertName` data is the same as my webpage's title, or a string associated with my webpage.

I have tried many tutorials already, but all just throw me errors, so I decided to try one last place before I just give in and make my labels static.

In case it helps, I have tried the following:

[First Try](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/aspnet/threads/149283/displaying-data-from-database-to-textbox)

[Second Try](http://forums.asp.net/t/1368431.aspx)

[Third Try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178694/how-to-display-database-data-in-textbox)

[Fourth Try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792167/how-to-get-data-to-textbox-from-the-database)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hopes you use c#

```
string MyPageTitle="MyPageTitle"; // your page title here
string myConnectionString = "connectionstring"; //you connectionstring goes here

SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand("select Price from Tickets where ConcertName ='" + MyPageTitle.Replace("'","''") + "'" , new SqlConnection(myConnectionString));
cmd.Connection.Open();
labelPrice.Text= cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString(); // assign to your label
cmd.Connection.Close();
```

Comment: Worked out that all my existing code was right, just needed the command string. It worked, so thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to bind the label to a data source. [Here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/64/Bind-Data-From-a-SqlDataSource-to-a-Label) is a great example that works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example protecting against SQL Injection and implicity disposes the SqlConnection object with the "using" statement.

```
string concert = "webpage title or string from webpage";

using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connString"].ConnectionString))
{
   string sqlSelect = @"select price 
                        from tickets 
                        where concert_name = @searchString";
   using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSelect, conn)) 
   {
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchString", concert);
      conn.Open();
      priceLabel.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
   }
}
```

If you're interested in researching ADO .Net a bit more, here is a link to the MSDN documentation for ADO .Net with framework 4.0

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h43ks021(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h43ks021%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: SqlCommand implements IDisposable too - why not have that in a using statement as well?